# Angularjs filter ng-repeat lists of objects base on it's sub array

Tags: angularjs

I'm Learning Angularjs,
Im trying to get Countries with specific member ID:
if the country contain memberId of "1" it should be shown.

```
<ul ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:memberId = 1">
   <li>
      {{country.Name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

this is my lists

```
        $scope.countries = [
            {
              "Name" : "UK",
              "memberId" : ["3"]
            },
            {
              "Name" : "USA",
              "memberId" : ["2"]          
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Mexico",
              "memberId" : ["1", "4"]                 
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Germany",
              "memberId" : ["1", "3"]                 
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Canada",
              "memberId" : ["1", "4"]                 
            }

        ]
```

is it possible to only show countries with memberId of "1" ?

Comment: the code seems to be `OK` what's your problem ?

Comment: it does not work countries like UK and USA still appears. and no consol.log() error showing also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is perfectly fine, following is your code, i have just added a `input` to show the dynamic filter

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('someCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [
            {
              "Name" : "UK",
              "memberId" : ["3"]
            },
            {
              "Name" : "USA",
              "memberId" : ["2"]          
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Mexico",
              "memberId" : ["1", "4"]                 
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Germany",
              "memberId" : ["1", "3"]                 
            },
            {
              "Name" : "Canada",
              "memberId" : ["1", "4"]                 
            }

        ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="someCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="memberId"/>
<ul ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:memberId">
   <li>
      {{country.Name}}
   </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: you are right, I dont know how, my Vhost, when I restart it, the code works.